# How to convert string into decimal?

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I text box i have a value:

```
1212,12
```

Additionally my text box have a mask:

```
MaskType=Numeric
EditMask='n2'
```

i try to parse it:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var value = decimal.Parse(myTextBox.Text, culture);
```

but get value=121212 when expected value=1212.12

What can be wrong?

Comment: Your problem is that `,` isn't a decimal separator in `en-US` culture, its a thousands separator. Use the correct culture or use the correct decimal separator.

Comment: you always want to replace " , " by " . " ?

Comment: Clearly your text box is not `en-US` culture, as pointed out by answers. Just using `fr-FR` is not necessarily the *right* solution, what is the *actual* culture of your input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a missmatching culture:

> 1212,12

and

> en-US

Either use `.` as a decimal separator (i.e. `1212.12`) or a culture which uses `,` (e.g. `de-DE`, `de-AT`, `fr-FR`), but `en-US` uses `.` as a decimal separator and `,` as a thousands separator.

Comment: @ChrFln Thank you. `fr-FR` helps me!

Comment: @KliverMax: You shouldn't simply use a culture which seems to work. You should adapt it to match your UI-culture and possibly instruct or limit the user to enter the correct format...

Answer (score 4):

`en-US` seperates the position after decimal point with a `.` instead of a `,`

try another culture or set myTextBox.Text to 1212.12

Answer (score 1):

`en-US` culture have [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) as a `.` not `,` but it has [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) as a `,`

That's why it thinks your `,` is `NumberGroupSeparator` and that's why it parses as `121212`.

As a solution, you can use different [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) which has `,` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` or you can clone your `en-US` culture with [`CultureInfo.Clone` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` property to `,` and changing it `NumberGroupSeparator` property something else.

```
string s = "1212,12";
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
decimal value = decimal.Parse(s, culture); // 1212.12
```

Answer (score 1):

Either change the separator or change the culture:

For en-US culture separator is `.`

If you want to use separator `,` use `fr-FR` culture !

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
var value = decimal.Parse(myTextBox.Text, culture);
```